# React CSS Transition Group not activating on leave (Redux)

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

On clicking a "remove" button, I want an animation to remove an item and have the rest of the collection either re-render or "slide up" to fill empty space.

I followed the facebook tutorial, and while I can get items to "fade in" on render, they do not seem to animate upon leaving.

component-code

```
export class PlannerFill extends Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  componentWillMount() { 
    this.props.fetch()

  }

  renderCard(element, key){    
    return (      
      <Card rounded={true} width={400} key={key}>
        <Heading level={2} size={3}>{element.name}</Heading>          
      </Card>
    )
  }

  render() {        
    return (              
        <section className={`${styles}`}>        
          <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
              transitionAppear={true} 
              transitionName="example" 
              transitionAppearTimeout={1500} transitionEnterTimeout={1500} transitionLeaveTimeout={1300}>                    
          {this.props.fridgeItems.map((element, key) => this.renderCard(element, key))}                  
          </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        </section>
    );
  }

}
```

CSS style sheet

```
.example-leave {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .example-leave.example-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
  }
}
```

I'm using redux to handle state, but I don't think that could be a problem. Just in case, here's the reducer that handles state change:

```
case SUBTRACT_FILLERPLAN:
      console.log("subtract from fridge reducer")
      const recipe = action.payload
      let fridgeCopy = state.fridgeItems.slice()
      const indexRecipe = fridgeCopy.indexOf(recipe)      
      fridgeCopy.splice(indexRecipe, 1)  
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        fridgeItems: fridgeCopy
      })
```